# How are these two theorems about linear independence equivalent/saying the same thing?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

I am reading through Friedberg, Spence, and Insel's book on Linear Algebra. In section 1.5, the section introducing the notions of linear dependence and independence, the following statement is made:

> Given a vector space $V$, if no proper subset of $S$ of $V$ generates the span of $S$, then $S$ is linearly independent.

I understand this statement, and I am able to prove it.

Then, almost immediately afterwards, the following theorem is given:

> Let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$, and let $v$ be a vector in $V$ which is not in $S$. Then $S\cup \{ v \}$ is linearly dependent if and only if $v\in\text{span}(S)$.

I also understand and am able to prove this statement.

However, in between these two statements, a claim is made that they are equivalent. And this is where I am having trouble. I am unable to see how these two theorems mean the same thing. Any help clarifying why these two are equivalent would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the definition of linear independence in this text is as follows:

> A subset of a vector space that is not linearly dependent is called linearly independent.

and the definition of linear dependence used here is:

> A subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is called linearly dependent if there exist a finite number of distinct vectors $u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$ in $S$ and scalars $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$, not all zero, such that $\sum_{i=0}^n c_iu_i = 0$.

Comment: This is not clear.  The first would appear to be a *definition* of linear independence.  The second presumes that this notion is already defined (else what might "Let $S$ be a linear independent subset of $V$" mean?).  I don't see an easy way to turn the second into a definition.   Are you saying that there is another definition of linear independence you are following?  If so, you should provide that definition.

Comment: @lulu I have edited w/ the definitions of linear dependence/independence the book is using. The book presents both of the first two statements as results, not definitions, regarding linear independence.

Comment: Ok, so then I agree that both statements are (easy) consequences of the definition (note that your definition has a typo, the first "independent" was meant to be "dependent").  But I still don't know what "equivalent" might mean.  You could use the first as a definition and deduce the second from that, but I don't really see how to go the other way.  Maybe if you are assuming that $S$ is finite or something like that, but not generally.

Comment: @lulu whoops, thank you I have corrected the typo in the definition.

Comment: I would think that the two statements are "equivalent" formulations of linear independence. Not quite in the sense of typical equivalence as one being true if and only if the other is true and rather in the sense that both can be used and achieve the same goal. The first statement is the idea of a linear indepent set as a minimal generator of the span (of itself) whilst the second one is something else I cannot quite summarize.

Comment: Saying two theorems are equivalent is vague. In general it makes no sense. I think, you may misinterpreted or misread some statements in Friedberg book.